# CPU and RAM upgrades Inspiron 13 7347

Tags: cpu, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 13, 7347 i3 (4010U) 2 in 1 laptop.  Can I upgrade to a faster CPU (i5 4210U) and if so are there any advantages to doing so (i.e. ability to increase RAM or get better screen resolution)?  Will do this myself provided the CPU is not soldered in place.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, hardware recommendation questions are off-topic as they [tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and often aren't useful to other readers. Instead of asking for a specific product, you should ask about *how* to find a particular device that meets your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you could replace the CPU...

According to [CPUBoss](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i5-4210U-vs-Intel-Core-i3-4010U) there is very little to be gained, performance wise, by doing such an upgrade.

You will not be able to increase your screen resolution, as the graphics component of the two CPU's are identical, "Intel HD Graphics 4400".

As the ability to increase RAM is determined by the chipset, Intel series 8, which is a non-replaceable part of the motherboard. You will not be able to gain anything in this respect either. Your specific model doesn't support any upgrade to the 8 GB of memory, which the laptop is born with. [Source](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Dell/inspiron-13-%287347%29).

All-in-all: *not worth it*.

Comment: I'm not sure the CPU boss scores are a good visual indicator since they are normalised against other CPU's. If you look at some of the raw results (e.g. PassMark) the i5 is about 40% faster.